# How to add plugins via docker compose cammand option?

Tags: wordpress, bash, docker-compose

I  need to download some free plugins from wordpress website and move that folders to plugins folder via command property in the docker-compose

Is there any way to execute shell script after the docker compose is completed?

```
> command: apt-get install -y curl  curl -SL
https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/advanced-custom-fields.5.7.12.zip
```

or a bash script for this?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) says:

> The command can also be a list, in a manner similar to dockerfile:
>
> command: ["bundle", "exec", "thin", "-p", "3000"]

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
docker-compose run <your_service> apt-get install -y curl  
docker-compose run <your_service> curl -SL https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/advanced-custom-fields.5.7.12.zip
```

You can even do it in 1 command but I'm guessing the installation is one off and you might include that in your image ;)

Hope this helps.